# Three.js - add shadows to area light using Deferred Rendering

Tags: rendering, three.js, webgl, deferred, shadows

I'm using WebGLDeferredRenderer for a simple scene (made by a cube simulating a room and two small cubes for testing shadows) but i can't show any shadows generated from the areaLight used in the scene!

In [this demo](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgldeferred_arealights.html) there are 3 area lights but none of them generate shadows over a single object (they just illuminate the "room").

Is there any particular shader i can use to solve this problem? Or better...is there any chance to cast shadow in deferred rendering? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shadows are not currently supported in three.js r.56 using deferred rendering with `WebGLDeferredRenderer`.

Here are two examples where point lights and spot lights cast shadows using deferred rendering in three.js, but they are using a *modified version of the library*.

http://alteredqualia.com/three/examples/webgl_deferred_shadowmap.html

http://alteredqualia.com/three/examples/webgl_deferred_shadowmap_point.html

There are no examples of area lights yet, however.

So what you want is doable, just not yet supported, and not with area lights.

three.js r.56

Comment: yes i've already seen those demos and i've also noticed that they are using a different version of the three.js library (it has been compressed too) but i thought there was some "official" method

Comment: In the links above, alteredqualia just used a custom version of threejs based on r55. There is no official method of doing it so dar. So forget about it for now or implement it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Use directional or point lights. Area light do not cast shadows.

Comment: none of them (point,directional,area) cast shadows in deferred rendering mode.

Answer (score 0):

I believe area light shadows are not yet implemented, although someone is probably working on it so it might be possible in the future. You could try to do it yourself but that would need some serious programming skills, its not an easy problem to solve :)

I think currently you can use spot and directional light shadows in deferred renderer, possibly even point light shadows.

You could fake shadows by using a different light type with low intensity for the shadows only, but that might look a bit wonky.

Comment: Does this answer add something more?

Comment: You wrote the same answer as below but with more words.

Comment: Did I not explain the reason why area lights don't cast shadows (development status) or elaborate on how one might approach working around the problem, so the answer could be useful in the future too? Besides I was already halfway finishing the answer when your post appeared. I don't see a reason for butthurt, as far as I know we are not in a competition or anything.

Comment: @yaku no lights method ever supported in deferred rendering mode, even point light or directional lights.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to push back your shadowmapping source based on how big the area is...  you can also eyeball futzing with the percentage closer filtering depending on how far back you have to push your shadowcaster.